# Oracle to Redshift query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to run below query and getting the error.
ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error. How can I re write subquery without altering the result. Highlighted in bold is causing the issue.

SELECT
bin_max,
bin_count,
ROUND(RATIO_TO_REPORT(bin_count) over (), 5) bin_percent
FROM
(
SELECT
bin_max,
cum_count - lag(cum_count, 1) over (ORDER BY bin_max) bin_count
FROM
(
SELECT
b.bin_max,
(select COUNT(*)
FROM ndw_owner.MBP_USER_LOGINS_BY_USER ulbu
WHERE
ulbu.DAYS_SINCE_FIRST_LOGIN > 30
**and ulbu.PROJECTED_30_DAY_LOGINS <= b.bin_max**
) cum_count
FROM
(SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 1 AS BIN_MAX
UNION
SELECT 2 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 3 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 4 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 5 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 10 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 15 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 20 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 30 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 40 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 60 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 80 AS BIN_MAX UNION
SELECT 99999999 AS BIN_MAX
)
) b
)
);

Answer (score 0):

Change the sub query to perform an inequality join between b and ulbu.  This will make the data you need in the top query.